# Getting a value from a higher databinding path

Tags: xaml

I have an object that contains a control defined in a control template, and an object which it gets notifications from.

These notification object keeps track of the status of the object, which translates on the screen to the colour in this instance, although they are used in other areas of the UI to reflect the state of these objects.

The rectangle colour changes fine on the status change, but I have another property which provides the foreground colour of the text. 
However, because of the ContentPresenter getting the text from the control, I can no longer get the foreground colour with the TextBlock.Foreground setter in the style, as the binding is pointing elsewhere.

I could put the name of the object in the notification object as well which would get rid of this question and problem, but I have run up against a similar issue in other places, and as I am new to WPF would like to know the way to do it.

This is the main relevant part of the ControlTemplate 'AnimatedTemplate':

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="ColourFill" Stroke="White" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
   <Rectangle.Fill>
     <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=FillColour}"/>
   </Rectangle.Fill>
   <Rectangle.Style>
   <Style>
     <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Active}" Value="True" >
         <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
           <BeginStoryboard> ... </BeginStoryboard>
         </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
       </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                  Margin="2" 
                  TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                  TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
  <ContentPresenter.Style>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" 
              Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
              Converter={StaticResource PushPinContentSizeConverter}}" />
      <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" 
              Value="{Binding Path=TextColour}"/>
    </Style>
  </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```

this is created with:

```
ControlTemplate template = (ControlTemplate)_window.FindResource("AnimatedTemplate");
Control c = new ContentControl();
c.Template = template;
c.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, displayName);
c.DataContext = <the notification object referred to as the first binding>
_window.d1overlay.Children.Add(c);
```

Comment: "the binding is pointing elsewhere" -- what binding is pointing... what? I don't get it. BTW who's setting the `ContentTemplate`? Setting the text foreground in the `ContentTemplate` should (I think) work, But if you want all that formatting responsibility centralized here (which makes sense to me), maybe insist on `Content` being a string, and display it in a `TextBlock` in your `ControlTemplate` instead of in a `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: This is part of the ControlTemplate which is provided for a control when it is created (in c#), so the ContentTemplate is pointing to the control. The 'Content' is the value set in the control with control.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, displayName); - and yes, I could put it in the notification object, but it is more generic question of how can I get a previously used datacontext, or pass parameters

Comment: "the ContentTemplate is pointing to the control" -- I'm sorry, I don't understand what that means. I don't know how to point a ContentTemplate to a control. For me ContentTemplate has always been a `DataTemplate`. Can you show me the code where "the ContentTemplate is pointing to the control"?

Comment: ok - that was a mess, I will add it to the question

Comment: Thanks! What method was that in? Finally, you aren't doing anything with `ContentTemplate` there.

Comment: What is `element`? It's hard to figure out code when there's no context, identifiers are unidentified, and you don't even know what method it's in.

Comment: The element is the object that owns the notificationObject and the control, which lives in a big database of other controls. I didn't see it has a relevance to this question, but yes it is confusing there so I have taken it out. The only relevant object is the control (the ContentPresenter) and the notification object, that has the FillColour and TextColour properties

Comment: Well, I can't make any sense out of what you're doing so good luck. My suggestions with the CONTENT template and using a TextBlock will both work (the latter, you'll need the content to be a string, which you consider unimportant, but appears to be the case).